# Can I dynamically create RabbitMQ shovel from my NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp, rabbitmq-shovel, node-amqplib

RabbitMQ shovel plugin provides an HTTP API to create & configure shovels. Assuming that I have enabled shovel & shovel management plugin for my RabbitMQ server instance, can I dynamically create shovels from my NodeJS app?

I currently use amqplib to connect to an exchange. https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html

However I don't see any API to dynamically create a shovel. Is this achievable or are there any other libraries that support this?

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-shovel-management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[amqplib](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node) does not provide any specific method to create dynamically shovels, but you can do that using the **Management HTTP-based API** as specified in the docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-dynamic.html#tutorial

So, in pure Node.js, this is and example of HTTP request (PUT method) to create a shovel programmatically:

```
var http = require('http');

var rabbit_host = "myrabbitmq.com";
var token = Buffer.from("admin:admin_pwd").toString('base64');
var shovel_name = "my_shovel";

var payload = {
    "component": "shovel",
    "vhost": "/",
    "name": "my_shovel",
    "value": {
        "src-uri": "amqp://user1:pwd1@myrabbitmq.com",
        "src-exchange": "test",
        "dest-uri": "amqp://user2:pwd2@anotherbroker.com",
        "dest-exchange-key": "test2",
        "add-forward-headers": false,
        "ack-mode": "on-confirm",
        "delete-after": "never"
    }
};

var options = {
  "host": rabbit_host,
  "port": 15672,
  "path": "/api/parameters/shovel/%2F/" + shovel_name,
  "method": "PUT",
  "headers": { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + token,
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
  }
}

var callback = function(response) {
    var str = ''
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log("end: response="+str);
    });
}

var body = JSON.stringify(payload);
http.request(options, callback).end(body).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("error: " + e.message);
});
```

Obviously host "myrabbitmq.com" must be accessible from Node.js script on port 15672.

The example above creates a shovel from "myrabbitmq.com" to "anotherbroker.com", specifying exchanges for routing messages.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I assumed I would have to do if amqp library did not provide an API for creating dynamic shovels. Wasn't sure if there's any other library that provided APIs for this. The example will definitely help me a lot when I implement dynamic shovels.